# Como fazer um sistema manual para checar novas atualizações?

Tags: android, app

O meu aplicativo não será publicado na Google Play, portanto eu preciso de fazer um sistema para checar novas atualizações e baixá-las, sem depender da Google Play. E de preferência sem gastar nada, utilizando serviços gratuitos (como o Dropbox ou afins).
Como fazer isto? Poderiam me ajudar por favor? Expliquem detalhadamente. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Mas queres que a tua aplicação cheque automaticamente se existem atualizações?

Comment: @JorgeB. Era para checar manualmente mesmo. Mas já foi resolvido! Obrigado pelo apoio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom, basicamente te darei a ideia de como isso funciona e você implementa ok.

Você deve possuir um servidor onde exista um arquivo que lhe diga qual versão está publicada atualmente.

Exemplo:

Na pasta raiz do seu servidor (servidor é o software ok), você tem uma pasta VersionPublish, dentro dela você pode ter um arquivo em XML, por exemplo, contendo o nome da versão atual, número do código, data de publicação, etc.

E também, dentro dessa pasta raiz, o último arquivo APK condizente com a descrição no XML.

Assim, você faz seu aplicativo consultar o servidor.

Exemplo:

Sua aplicação envia uma requisição ao servidor informando a versão (número do código) do aplicativo atualmente instalado. O servidor verifica a versão atualmente publicada é superior a informada pela aplicação que fez a requisição.

Se sim, ele retorna uma resposta verdadeira (aí você mostra o botão de atualizar, ou uma mensagem ao usuário perguntando se ele deseja atualizar, etc).

Quando o usuário informa que deseja atualizar, você envia uma outra requisição ao servidor solicitando o download do arquivo publicado.

Após baixar, o usuário instala a APK normalmente.

Considere que você não pode faz o mesmo tipo de atualização realizada pela Play Store.

Se você tem receio do usuário ficar com seu APK no celular, basta baixar numa pasta interna e em seguida chamar a Intent de instalação do próprio SO.

Esse foi um exemplo simples! Considere toda a engenharia por trás de segurança, etc.

Comment: Belo exemplo e ideia! Depois de muita pesquisa e buscas intensas, achei uma solução: uma simples livraria para aplicar em meu app, o [Android WVersion Manager](https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WVersionManager). Obrigado pelo apoio!

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa construir um mecanismo para que seu app chame o servidor periodicamente e verifique se existe uma versão nova.

Se existir, o app precisa baixar o update e instalar ele com algo similar a essa AsyncTask:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
String path = "/sdcard/SeuApp.apk";
try {
    URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.connect();

    int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

    // baixar o arquivo
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path);

    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    long total = 0;
    int count;
    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("SeuApp", "Não funcionou tão bem...");
    Log.e("SeuApp", e.getMessage());
}
return path;
}

// começar instalação abrindo o arquivo
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String path) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive" );
    Log.d("SeuApp", "Começando a instalação do .apk");
    this.context.startActivity(i);
}
```