# Como atualizar meu aplicativo pelo APK sem perder meu banco de dados SQLite?

Tags: android

Criei um aplicativo, fiz cadastros no banco *Sqlite*, mas quado eu criar novas funções para o aplicativo como faço para atualizar sem desinstalá-lo?

**Obs:** não uso *Google Play*, eu instalo direto do *Apk* que eu crio.

Comment: Alterar o app sem atualizá-lo acho que não tem como, você precisa de uma forma de atualizar o APK(como ocorre na play store), da uma olhada no link que segue: [Como fazer um sistema manual para checar novas atualizações?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23010/28595)

Comment: eu quero atualiza-lo, mas sem desinstalar o aplicativo, não quero perder as informações no banco

Comment: @Tahatsu dê uma olhada na resposta [Como atualizar um app proprietário?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148071/35406)

Comment: Não precisa perder as informações, só acontece isso se você programar para apagar na instalação.

Comment: Como você esta fazendo para criar o Banco?
Coloca o código aqui para a gente avaliar.

Comment: o banco deve estar numa pasta do usuário do dispositivo.

Comment: Quando você atualiza você não perde o banco. A não ser que você desinstale o aplicativo já instalado.

Comment: Se somente instalar o apk "por cima" da versao anterior, praticamente um update não acontece nada. Agora se desinstalar o app ai ja era o banco, a menos que tenha feito como falou o @DanielOmine falou e o banco esteja em uma pasta "fora" do app, que dependendo da situação pode não ser uma boa ideia, mas não deixade ser uma alternativa.

Comment: Se você quiser alterar o banco, criar colunas ou tabelas você deve fazer o  migration no seu app, ou seja escrever o script para dar o "upgrade" no seu banco, você pode usar o [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) que já é nativo no android, [aqui](http://www.greenmoonsoftware.com/2012/02/sqlite-schema-migration-in-android/) existe um exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao atualizar seu APK na playstore seu banco de dados NÃO será apagado.
Na sua classe databasehelper vai ter um método **onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)** onde **oldVersion** é a versão anterior do seu banco no device do usuário e **newVersion** é a nova versão.

Exemplo

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    switch (oldVersion){
        case 1;
            //TODO alteras campos da vesao 1 para versão 2
            break;
        case 2;
            //TODO alteras campos da vesao 2 para versão 3
            break;
        case 3;
            //TODO alteras campos da vesao 3 para versão 4
            break;
    }
}
```

Caso você precise saber a nova versão do banco para fazer a alteração use a variável **newVersion**