# Atualização do banco do aplicativo

Tags: angular, ionic2

Sou iniciante na programação de aplicativos. Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em `ionic 2` com o `angular 2`. Surgiu uma duvida, eu tenho uma `provider` e nele eu faço toda a parte do banco de dados usando o `SQLite`, so que surgiu a necessidade de adicionar um campo a tabela , ate ai tudo , acrescentei o campo, mas teve um problema eu tive que desinstalar o aplicativo para que atualização funcionasse, ai nesse cado eu perdi todos os dados , praticamente zerei o banco para que atualização fosse instalada.

Teria alguma forma de fazer essa atualização sem precisar zerar o banco desinstalando o aplicativo ?

Segue meu `provider`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

@Injectable()
 export class RomaneioBdSql {
 storage: any;
 public romaneios: Array<Object>;

 constructor(public http: Http, public sqlite: SQLite) {
   this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'infoged.db',
    location: 'default'
  }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql('create table IF NOT EXISTS tb_romaneio(id_romaneio INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,' +
    'romaneio_name VARCHAR(32),' +
    'romaneio_motorista VARCHAR(52) default NULL, ' +
    'romaneio_nota VARCHAR(19),' +
    'romaneio_serie VARCHAR(9),' +
    'romaneio_sincronizada integer(1) default 0' +
    ')', {})
    .then(ed => /*alert(JSON.stringify(ed))*/ed)
    .catch(e => alert(JSON.stringify(e)));
}).catch(e => alert(JSON.stringify(e)));
```

}

Comment: Este post deve te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152297/como-atualizar-meu-aplicativo-pelo-apk-sem-perder-meu-banco-de-dados-sqlite

Comment: Obrigado Nilson , começou a dar uma clareada!